# Watch videos on updated MacBook Pro and latest Tor browser

Tags: mac

I have a MacBook. Pro and whenever I try to watch movies with my Tor browser it constantly buffers. Is there anything I can do to stop this?

Answer (score 0):

It's fine: many exit nodes are busy and do not have that much speed, so you should either restart your Tor browser to re-connect to tor network and maybe you will have a new exit node. If you're using Tor control protocol - try sending SIGNAL NEWNYM to Tor to change the exit point. That's all you can do - there's no way to alter the exit node's speed